# Get user directory in Xcode build script

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unix, build

Is it possible to access the user directory "~/" in an Xcode build script phase?

Right now I am trying to directly use "~/" but on compilation it complains the directory doesn't exist. Is there another way to get the user directory (or the name of the user folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the $HOME environmental variable.
So for the Application Support folder, you would do:

"$HOME/Library/Application Support"

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I just used this "$HOME/"